# Why callback not returned calling API on browser

Tags: javascript, browser, callback

I am running this script in chrome browser

```
https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?callback=cb
```

I am not getting callback method which i specified?

is this only works in script tags?  can't i load directly on browser and see result ?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to see, or expecting to happen, but you can see the result of a JSON-P callback in your browser.

If I enter this URL:

`https://skyviewcafe.com/atlas/?q=Tirana&callback=foo`

I get this output in Chrome:

```
/**/ typeof foo === 'function' && foo({"originalSearch":"Tirana","normalizedSearch":"TIRANA","matches":[{"matchedByAlternateName":false,"matchedBySound":false,"city":"Tirana","county":"","state":"Tiranë","country":"ALB","longCountry":"Albania","flagCode":"al","latitude":41.3275,"longitude":19.8189,"elevation":0,"zone":"Europe/Tirane","zip":"","rank":5,"placeType":"P.PPLC","source":2,"displayName":"Tirana, ALB (Albania)","zoneOffset":60,"zoneDst":60},{"matchedByAlternateName":false,"matchedBySound":false,"city":"Tiranagama","county":"","state":"","country":"LKA","longCountry":"Sri Lanka","flagCode":"lk","latitude":6.1333,"longitude":80.1167,"elevation":0,"zone":"Asia/Colombo","zip":"80244","rank":2,"placeType":"P.PPL","source":1,"displayName":"Tiranagama, LKA (Sri Lanka)","zoneOffset":330,"zoneDst":0}],"time":8.630123138427734,"count":2});
```

You can see clearly how the JSON that comes back is wrapped inside a call to the specified callback function, `foo`.

Comment: yes in ur case it's json data returns looks working pretty fine. can i do with js file. like google api file (https://apis.google.com/js/client.js) , i want to wrap it in callback method.

Comment: Callbacks like this are only meant to work with JSON data. While JSON is also valid JavaScript, the reverse is seldom true that JavaScript is valid JSON. The script at that particular URL (apis.google.com/js/client.js) isn't valid JSON, and wouldn't function as material that can get stuffed inside a function callback.

Comment: Further, honoring the callback parameter is not done by the web browser, it's something that the server you're making the request from has to actively decide to perform. In this case the Google server is simply serving up a static file, and wouldn't have any reason to look for, or do anything with, the callback parameter.

Comment: This comment you could have added it to your answer. that's pretty much clear now. Thank you!